# c# Android NFCAdapter - Issue with AuthenticateSectorWithKeyA & Hex

Tags: c#, android, nfc, maui, nfcadapter

No problem passing the following Keys and authenticating the sector with `AuthenticateSectorWithKeyA`.

```
byte[] keybytes = new byte[] { (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff, (byte)0xff };
byte[] keybytes = new byte[] { (byte)0xAB, (byte)0xCD, (byte)0xEF, (byte)0x12, (byte)0x34, (byte)0x56 };
var auth = tag.AuthenticateSectorWithKeyA(0, keybytes);
```

But when I try the following Key it fails to authenticate. Error Received - " Transceive Failed"

```
byte[] keybytes = new byte[] { (byte)0x19, (byte)0x23, (byte)0x86, (byte)0x18, (byte)0x05, (byte)0x00 };
```

I suspect the issue is with the final 2 bytes `(byte)0x05, (byte)0x00` which are loaded into the array as 5 and 0.

Bit new to Hex and byte arrays, any help welcome.

Tried:

```
byte[] keybytes = new byte[] { (byte)0xAB, (byte)0xCD, (byte)0xEF, (byte)0x12, (byte)0x34, (byte)0x56 };
```

OK

Tried:

```
byte[] keybytes = new byte[] { (byte)0x19, (byte)0x23, (byte)0x86, (byte)0x18, (byte)0x05, (byte)0x00 };
```

Result: Transceive Failed

Comment: According to the Android documentation: [Requires the Manifest.permission.NFC permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic#authenticateSectorWithKeyA(int,%20byte[])). Did you go through this step? Could you provide detailed error information?

Comment: I have the following in AndroidManifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC_TRANSACTION_EVENT" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE" />

Comment: UPDATE:
The correct error is that AuthenticateSectorWithKeyA returns false.
The Transceive Failed occurs on ReadBlock.

Comment: FInally to add:
I print and encode the cards. 
The card print software allows changes to sector keys. I change sector 0, KeyA. I input 192386180500 as the keyA for Sector 0.
I also use a time and attendance device with RFID reader, and also input the key above. This device reads the card.

Need to use this key as we have thousands of cards printed over the years.